# How can I display a meaningful login error messages to user within python-social-auth?

Tags: python, django, authentication, python-social-auth

I am using `python-social-auth` with Django 1.6 and things are working well.

I defined `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL` to point to a view I have within my app to show an error to the user when the login does not go as planned.

My system does not allow creation of new users. You must first log into your account using the regular credentials, associate your account with a social account, and only then can you log in using a social auth mechanism.

If a user attempts to log into my system using a social account which is not registered to a user within my system, I want to display a custom message. The problem is, the view located at `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL` does not receive any info about what the error could be. The best I can do is say "An error occurred while trying to log in."

How would I trap such errors and display a custom message to my users when that particular error happens?

Comment: as far as i remember user permission is required for the authentication when you use python-social-auth... until you don't provide correct password you will not get pass through the social site login page..

Comment: @krystian: I'm having the same issue. where you able to fix this?

Comment: @udo To handle the case where the user has not been associated yet, I yanked the `social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user` pipeline step and added my own custom `social_user` step. My version is a copy of the original, with one tweak. It handles the case where `get_social_auth` does not return a value and the `social` variable is `None`. In that case, it shows my own custom view telling the user that the account is not yet associated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the middleware from the django_app:

https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/526439ac66b00ce801e4fc5df89633a66eb8ffb2/social/apps/django_app/middleware.py

and either create your own based on this or extended by overriding. As mentioned there, probably the get_message method.

Comment: I have a custom check for an existing user that is included in the pipeline. How can I throw an exception so that PSA catches it and redirects to SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL with the exception message?

Answer (score 1):

to handle this, I do the following:

**settings.py**

```
...
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    # the custom pipeline step
    'accounts.views.user_details_after',
)
...
```

**views.py**

```
def user_details_after(strategy, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if not user:
        messages.info(strategy.request, "You have to sign up first.")
```

in the loging template I render the message to display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to just render the error page with the info you want, like

```
return render(
        request,
        "error.html",
        {
        "error_title":"Custom Error",
        "error_message":"This is an error"
        }
    )
```

and your `templates/error.html` template

```
<h1>{{ error_title }}</h1>
<p>{{ error_message }}</p>
```